# .csproj gets checked out if tfs server name is configured with ip

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

I have my tfs server name configured using the ip address and my colleagues are using the server name. 
I have something like this:

> http://x.y.x.t:8080/tfs/defaultcollection

and the others have something like this:

> http://tfs.orgname.net:8080/tfs/defaultcollection

Some csproj files have SccAuxPath set to the tfs server name, but these files get checked out locally and the tfs server name is replaced with the ip address.

Is there a way to avoid this? I am using VisualStudio 2015.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got into this situation. I can't remember the last time I saw anything within the `SccXxx` properties in a proj file other than `SAK`

Comment: I have found this one as fixer http://bartwullems.blogspot.ro/2013/07/team-foundation-server-map-different.html but I am wondering if it possible to use both server name or ip for tfs name and let VisualStudio know about them

Comment: @Angela Please post the answer for your question and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Angela using IP address and server name are both supported in VS to connect to TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this one as fixer http://bartwullems.blogspot.ro/2013/07/team-foundation-server-map-different.html